# Wordpress subpages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have been asked to design a  site in Wordpress .Just a rough design looks like given below :

[image]

so what i want is when i click on  **ABOUT**   it should expand and display the page content.Somewhat like this  :

[image]

Any one has any idea regarding displaying the page content at same place instead opening in new page  or window ?

Thanks in advance..   :)

**Edit1**

the below is the php code of page.php

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
 <div id="content" class="page">

 <div id="box">
  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <?php the_content(); ?><br /><div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i want menus to be displayed as shown in the images .So as per the tutorial of **Arconix Shortcode Collection** it says i have to write the code as for example

```
  [accordions]
  [accordion title="About"]
  About Content here
  [/accordion]
  [accordion title="Results"]
  Results Content here
  [/accordion]
  [accordion title="People" last="last"]
  People Content here
  [/accordion]
  [/accordions]
```

Now in this instead of just the content watever we write i wanted it to be

1)content from a page for example in case of about its the content from page **About**(as pages can be created in wordpress Pages--->new page .So in case if i want to edit this i just go to pages and edit the about page).

2)and the content should get displayed only after mouse click..

**edit 2**

In the pages wherever I want to include **accordion** i select the given option from the pages

[image]

once i click on it .There is no option to select a page as shown below:

so anyone has any idea regarding this..?

[image]

Comment: It's called an accordion and done using JavaScript. 1st hit on Google: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/

Comment: ok thanks..but i am not familiar with coding in  javascript..so is there any other way ?or is it possible using php funtions?

Comment: Don't think so as PHP will always be executed server side and will therefore serve a static (rendered) document to the client requesting the page. If you want your site to "display the page content at same place instead opening in new page or window" you will have to use client side techniques (i.e. JavaScript).

Comment: thanks for quick reply .. but can you suggest some links of free wordpress themes with such design and accordion tabs?Because creating them using jquery will take a lot time rather then working and just modifying the installed ones...

Comment: I don't have any clues about wordpress themes, but why not just google "wordpress theme accordion". Yields a lot of results for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a WordPress plugin that can accomplish this easily - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/arconix-shortcodes/

Documentation for Accordions with this plugin at https://arconixpc.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4

(The plugin does much more as well.)

Comment: hello DaveP thanks ...the plugin is  interesting..and i think its going to be of great use .But i still have some doubts..i have edited the question..

Comment: I slightly misunderstood the original question, not realising that you wanted distinct WP pages in the accordion tabs. While this could be done, it would mean editing template files.

Comment: ok..editing template files meaning i l have to add the


 [Accordion ] Content {accordion] code in template files???