# wordpress multiple pages on one page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i am developing a CMS site in wordpress ...

the final web page should  some what look like :

[Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430123/wordpress-subpages)

I want just one page (front page) and on that i want to display subpages titles  in it. (About,Home,People)...

So when the subpage title   is clicked it should expand and display the the page content  in the panel,on  same page  and at same place.

any ideas regarding same?
Thanks in advance...:)

**EDIT1**

[accordions]
[accordion title="Accordion 1"]
Accordion 1 Content here
[/accordion]
[accordion title="Accordion 2"]
Accordion 2 Content here
[/accordion]
[accordion title="Accordion 3" last="last"]
Accordion 3 Content here
[/accordion]
[/accordions]

after puting the above code in the page content  looks like this:

[image]

but on click of **ACCORDION 1** its not getting expanded..

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own template, which does a query (checks for a subpage), and adds its content between div tags.

When it's done, then it's time for JS/jQuery . Search for tab jQuery scripts, so you get some information.

Anyway, you will mostly need to use hide() / show() functions to reach something like that.

Also, did you made that template, and are you familiar with programming in WP?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order,title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$my_pagelist = get_children($args);
?>
```

Above is code for displaying subpage content, below is the jQuery tutorial for tabs.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

**EDIT:**

Also, check this site - http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide it will show you some info about show/hide functions. Also more information about WP get_children function is found here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Comment: thanks..i am not so familiar with programming in WP..so was looking for some plugins...which will directly add the content with little or no coding..If you are know such plugins please provide me the links..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know any plugins like that. If you could tell me your theme name, I could create you a specific page with all these features you listed, since it's nothing hard. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, in the latest version of WordPress.

Login to your admin panel.

Click on the 'Settings' tab, then the 'Reading' sub-tab.

Change the 'Front page displays' option to 'A static page'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply......

yes i have a HOME page..which i have made as static..now there are many pages like About,People which i created in wordpress (pages-->add new ) .I want the contents of these pages to be displayed on the Home page..

Comment: Does the page you linked to not answer your question fully? The answers on there seem to solve your problem?